# Sub-values for a specific category in stack chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Is there a way to plot a stack chart wherein one specific category within the stack can be further sub-divided and displayed on the chart?  This way we can see the total for that category as well as the individual data values.

The image below shows the current state at the top and the desired state at the bottom:

[image]

Can this be done with macros ?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the data table row for Milk,

[image]

and re-plot the graph, you can then format the various milk bars to be the same color, and add an outline to distinguish them:

[image]

Double-click on each of the milk bars in turn to enter the dialog box for setting "Fill" and " Line".

Comment: You were way ahead of me on the edit.  It looked like you had left out the second graph and I just noticed that you did it on purpose.  Sorry about that.  :-)